# How to install python library Pyexiv2 and Gexiv2 on osx 10.6.8?

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, pyexiv2

Does anyone knows how to install the python library [pyexiv2](http://tilloy.net/dev/pyexiv2/) and/or Gexiv2 on Mac OSX, ideally on version 10.6.8 and in a virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) package manager:

```
brew install exiv2 pyexiv2
```

If you're using Macports, it also has exiv2 formulas:

http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=exiv

--Edit--

A side note: I got segfault at "import pyexiv2". It turned out I have system Python 2.7.2 and homebrew Python 2.73 intalled at the same time. The problem disappeared after I uninstalled the brewed Python. Related info can be found here:

https://answers.launchpad.net/pyexiv2/+question/212471

Comment: Well, that was pretty easy actually. At the time of asking the question, I spent hours trying to install both pyexiv2 and Gexiv2 but did not succeed. Meanwhile, I reinstalled OSX so I guess my problems came from my installation. Thank you very much.

Comment: pyexiv2 being deprecated, any idea about Gexiv2 installation?

Comment: For Gexiv2, you can still install the exiv2 library with homebrew and macports. And you'll have to download gexiv2 source and compile. I failed at the 'make' step, got complaints about wrong libtool arguments. I guess some difference between Linux and Mac casused this. I needed exiv2 for a quick task to batch edit the exif timestamp, and pyexiv2 worked for me so I didn't spend more time dig into why gexiv2 failed.

Comment: I would also like to make pyexiv2 work in a virtualenv env, do you know how to do that?

Comment: I manually copied the needed files and it works:
`cp -r /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyexiv2 /path_to_my_virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
cp /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/libexiv2python.so /path_to_my_virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages`

Comment: This answer does not work in OSX Yosemite. I opened a new thread about this here http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/177659/15504

Answer (score 4):

Gexiv2 is now available in [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), so just...

```
 brew install gexiv2
```