# pyexiv2 with homebrew python 2.7.4

Tags: python, homebrew, pyexiv2

I have just installed python (2.7.4) with brew on my macbook pro (10.7.5).
I also installed exiv2 and pyexiv2 with brew.
When I import pyexiv2 from the python interpreter, I got the following error :

Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)

What I should do to correct that (considering that I do not want to remove the brewed python as suggested in this thread:
[How to install python library Pyexiv2 and Gexiv2 on osx 10.6.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001174/how-to-install-python-library-gexiv2-on-osx-10-6-8))

Thanks a lot for any advice !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much searching and looking at a few complicated solutions across the web, I found a simple method to solve this problem, in the [Homebrew wiki itself](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues)!

The root of the problem is the [boost](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost/info) dependency library, which by default links to the system python and not a brewed python, from the [wiki](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues#python-segmentation-fault-11-on-import-):

> Note that e.g. **the boost bottle is built against system python and should be brewed from source to make it work with a brewed Python.** This can even happen when both python executables are the same version (e.g. 2.7.2). The explanation is that Python packages with C-extensions (those that have .so files) are compiled against a certain python binary/library that may have been built with a different arch (e.g. Apple's python is still not a pure 64bit). Other things can go wrong, too. Welcome to the dirty underworld of C.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

1. So first uninstall the dependency libraries and pyexiv2 itself with:

   ```
   brew rm $(brew deps pyexiv2)
   brew rm pyexiv2
   ```
2. Then install `boost` from source as indicated [here](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues#python-fatal-python-error-pythreadstate_get-no-current-thread):

   ```
   brew install boost --build-from-source
   ```

   Note: building boost might take time, so be patient, it took my system 27.9 mins! (output below)

   ```
   usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0: 9865 files, 568M, built in 27.9 minutes
   ```
3. Then reinstall pyexiv2 and dependencies:

   ```
   brew install pyexiv2
   ```

That's it, now importing pyexiv2 should work flawlessly.

Comment: Brewed in 29.5 minutes. Works like a charm. Thank you very very much!

Comment: This didn't work on El Capitan, boost was recompiled but the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

Check which Python you are running (`which python`), and run `python` with the `-v` option to see where it is looking for modules.  Check that all those things match your expectations.  Then run `brew doctor`, and if that doesn't complain about anything, report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bunch of trouble installing pyexiv2 with Homebrew on macOS Sierra using bool.dev's answer above. The Homebrewed pyexiv2 kept throwing a Segmentation Fault 11 on import.

I eventually got it installed and working with the Homebrewed Python by modifying bool.dev's answer with the following commands:

```
brew install boost --build-from-source
brew install boost-python
brew install exiv2
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/escaped/pyexiv2.git
```

I found the last line in the [following document](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/thumbor/stable/thumbor.pdf) on Page 30 after getting sucked down a Google hole.

Hope this helps!